# Reading large text files efficiently

Tags: php, performance, file

I have a couple of huge (`11mb` and `54mb`) files that I need to read to process the rest of the script. Currently I'm reading the files and storing them in an array like so:

```
$pricelist = array();
$fp = fopen($DIR.'datafeeds/pricelist.csv','r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
    if ($line) { 
        $pricelist[$line[2]] = $line;
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

.. but I'm constantly getting memory overload messages from my webhost. How do I read it more efficiently?

I don't need to store everything, I already have the keyword which exactly matches the array key `$line[2]` and I need to read just that one array/line.

Comment: import in to db perhaps

Comment: The files are updated daily, sometimes the columns are also moved so its not ideal to use a DB .. atleast not right now.

Comment: That file is currently read line by line. The problem is the in-memory usage caused by the array itself and is not about "reading" the file. You need to change the logic such that it *doesn't need to load all the data at once*, get a host with a larger memory limit, or use secondary storage (such as a DB, out-of-process cache, or other files) for the temporary/processing data, etc..

Comment: So if you already have the condition for when you want to save a line, can you not just use that to determine whether you add it to your array?

Comment: Instead of maintaining it all in memory, consider writing out results to another file - it will be very memory efficient then (and the speed may not be as slow as you'd perhaps think). Also: are you doing this inside a web process? If so, consider moving it to a cron - on shared hosts they are often not memory limited.

Comment: mysql LOAD DATA INFILE is very efficient, and still might be a solution

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly you have a known `key` value say `$my_key` ... so you can do this `if ($line && $line[2] == $my_key) { return $line;  } ` ... right ?

Comment: @Dagon can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the key why don't you filter out by the key? And you can check memory usage with memory_get_usage() function to see how much memory allocated after you fill your $pricelist array.

```
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
$yourKey = 'some_key';
$pricelist = array();
$fp = fopen($DIR.'datafeeds/pricelist.csv','r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
    if (isset($line[2]) && $line[2] == $yourKey) { 
        $pricelist[$line[2]] = $line;
        break;
        /* If there is a possiblity to have multiple lines
        we can store each line in a separate array element
        $pricelist[$line[2]][] = $line;
        */
    }
}
fclose($fp);
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
```

Comment: Don't forget to break out after you've got your line - there's no point in scanning through the rest of the file if you've already got the info you want.

Comment: Yes you are right @Eborbob if we are sure that there is only one line that works for us we can break the while for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (I have not checked if it works properly)

```
$data = explode("\n", shell_exec('cat filename.csv | grep KEYWORD'));
```

You will get all the lines containing the keyword, each line as an element of array.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Very good solution indeed. shell_exec returns with a whitespace (PHP 5.5.9, Linux Mint) if you surround shell_exec with a trim it looks much more better.
`$data = explode("\n", trim(shell_exec('cat filename.csv | grep KEYWORD')));`

Also there's a drawback, most of the hosting companies don't let customers to run shell_exec in a shared envorinment.

Answer (score 2):

I join what **user2864740** said : "*The problem is the in-memory usage caused by the array itself and is not about "reading" the file*"

My Solution is :

- Split your `$priceList` array
- Load only 1 at time a splitted Array in memory
- Keep the other splitted Arrays in an intermediate file

**N.B: i did not test what i've written**

```
<?php
    define ("MAX_LINE",         10000)  ;
    define ("CSV_SEPERATOR",    ',')    ;

    function intermediateBuilder ($csvFile, $intermediateCsvFile) {
        $pricelist              = array ();
        $currentLine            = 0;
        $totalSerializedArray   = 0;

        if (!is_file()) {
            throw new Exception ("this is not a regular file: " . $csv);
        }
        $fp = fopen ($csvFile, 'r');
        if (!$fp) {
            throw new Exception ("can not read this file: " . $csv);
        }

        while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, CSV_SEPERATOR)) !== FALSE) { 
            if ($line) { 
                $pricelist[$line[2]] = $line;
            }
            if (++$currentLine == MAX_LINE) {
                $fp2    = fopen ($intermediateCsvFile, 'a');
                if (!$fp) throw new Exception ("can not write in this intermediate csv file: " . $intermediateCsvFile);

                fputs  ($fp2, serialize ($pricelist) . "\n");
                fclose ($fp2);

                unset ($pricelist);
                $pricelist      = array ();
                $currentLine    = 0;
                $totalSerializedArray++;
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
        return $totalSerializedArray;
    }

    /**
      * @param array   : by reference unserialized array 
      * @param integer : the array number to read from the intermediate csv file; start from index 1
      * @param string  : the (relative|absolute) path/name of the intermediate csv file
      * @throw Exception
      */
    function loadArray (&$array, $arrayNumber, $intermediateCsvFile) {
        $currentLine    = 0;
        $fp             = fopen ($intermediateCsvFile, 'r');
        if (!$fp) {
            throw new Exception ("can not read this intermediate csv file: " . $intermediateCsvFile);
        }
        while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, CSV_SEPERATOR)) !== FALSE) { 
            if (++$currentLine == $arrayNumber) {
                fclose ($fp);
                $array  = unserialize ($line);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception ("the array number argument [" . $arrayNumber . "] is invalid (out of bounds)");
    }
```

**Usage example**

```
try {
    $totalSerializedArray = intermediateBuilder ($DIR . 'datafeeds/pricelist.csv', 
                                                 $DIR . 'datafeeds/intermediatePricelist.csv');

    $priceList   = array () ;
    $arrayNumber = 1;

    loadArray ($priceList, 
               $arrayNumber, 
               $DIR . 'datafeeds/intermediatePricelist.csv');
    if (!array_key_exists ($key, $priceList)) {
        if (++$arrayNumber > $totalSerializedArray) $arrayNumber = 1;
        loadArray ($priceList, 
                   $arrayNumber, 
                   $DIR . 'datafeeds/intermediatePricelist.csv');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // TODO : log the error ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the

```
if ($line) {
```

That only repeats the check from the loop condition.  If your file is 54MB, and you are going to retain every line from the file, as an array, plus the key from column 3 (which is hashed for lookup)... I could see that requiring 75-85MB to store it all in memory. That isn't much. Most wordpress or magento pages using widgets run 150-200MB. But if your host is set low it could be a problem.

You can try filtering out some rows by changing the if($line) to a if($line[1] == 'book') to reduce how much you store. But the only sure way to handle storing that much content in memory is to have that much memory available to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set bigger memory using this. You can change limit how you want.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

But also depents how you want that script use.